# Write file name based on return

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I'm creating a boto3 script that scrapes and uploads our entire accounts Public Ips and NatGateway Ips to our S3 bucket. I'm stuck on writing files for both returns. I would ideally like to write two separate files while still using the same filename variable you see in main(). Right now I can get this to work with only one return(either nat_ips or public_ips)

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
from csv import writer

def get_ips():

 # Uses STS to assume the role needed. 
 boto_sts=boto3.client('sts')
 sts_response = boto_sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::1234:role/foo',
    RoleSessionName='Foo'
)

 # Save the details from assumed role into vars
 sts_credentials = sts_response["Credentials"]
 session_id = sts_credentials["AccessKeyId"]
 session_key = sts_credentials["SecretAccessKey"]
 session_token = sts_credentials["SessionToken"]

# List and store all the regions
  ec2_client=boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=session_id,aws_secret_access_key=session_key,aws_session_token=session_token,region_name='us-west-1')
  all_regions=[region['RegionName'] for region in ec2_client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
  nat_ips = []
  public_ips = []
  for region in all_regions:
    max_results = 1000
    next_token = ''
    ec2_client=boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=session_id,aws_secret_access_key=session_key,aws_session_token=session_token,region_name=region)
    session=boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=session_id, aws_secret_access_key=session_key, aws_session_token=session_token, region_name=region)
    while next_token or next_token == '':
        response = ec2_client.describe_nat_gateways(MaxResults=max_results, NextToken=next_token)
        filters = [{'Name':'tag:Name', 'Values':['*sgw-eip']}]
        get_ips = ec2_client.describe_addresses(Filters=filters)
        for gateway in response["NatGateways"]:
            for address in gateway["NatGatewayAddresses"]:
                nat_ips.append(address["PublicIp"]+'/32')
        for eip_dict in get_ips['Addresses']:
            public_ip_string = eip_dict['Tags'][0]['Value'] + ' : ' + eip_dict['PublicIp']
            public_ips.append(public_ip_string)
        next_token = response.get("NextToken", None)

return nat_ips, public_ips

def _s3_upload(filename):
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
 bucket = 'foo-bar'
 object_name = 'foo/'
 s3.meta.client.upload_file(Filename=filename,Bucket=bucket,Key=object_name+filename)
 print(f'Uploading {filename} to {bucket}')

def write_list_to_file(filename, data):
 lines_string = '\n'.join(str(x) for x in data)
 with open(filename,'w') as output:
    output.writelines(lines_string)
    print(f'Writing file to {filename}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
 date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
 # Stuck here since I want to make it one variable
 filename_nat_ips = f'natgateway_ips{date}.csv'
 filename_sga_ips = f'sga_ips{date}.csv'
 public_ips = get_ips()
 nat_ips = get_ips()
 print(filename)
 write_list_to_file(filename, nat_ips)
 _s3_upload(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are already returning a tuple of `public_ips` and `nat_ips` from your `get_ips()` function. So in your main, you could collect them together as well.

You might try something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
     # Stuck here since I want to make it one variable
     filename_nat_ips = f'natgateway_ips{date}.csv'
     filename_sga_ips = f'sga_ips{date}.csv'
     nat_ips, public_ips = get_ips()
     write_list_to_file(filename_nat_ips, nat_ips)
     write_list_to_file(filename_public_ips, public_ips)
     _s3_upload(filename_nat_ips)
     _s3_upload(filename_public_ips)
```

Comment: This is how I had it. But removed it because I wanted to find a way to loop through the public_ips and nat_ips to create a variable named filename instead of filename_nat_ips. Since filename is being used on the s3_upload data and the write to file.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it right the first time. And was trying to make it more complicated.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename_nat_ips = f'natgateway_ips{date}.csv'
filename_sga_ips = f'sga_ips{date}.csv'
nat_ips, public_ips = get_ips()
print(filename_nat_ips)
print(filename_sga_ips)
write_list_to_file(filename_nat_ips, nat_ips)
write_list_to_file(filename_sga_ips, public_ips)
_s3_upload(filename_nat_ips)
_s3_upload(filename_sga_ips)
```